# How to extract the shape parameter of a Fréchet fitted model using the R SPREDA package?

Tags: r, distributions, extreme-value

I'm trying to follow [this post](https://blogs2.datall-analyse.nl/2016/02/17/extreme_value_analysis_maxima/#more-120), which fits a Frechet distribution to some wind measurements as follows:

```
require('SPREDA')
require(e1071)
require(extRemes)
require(survival)

#The R functions for performing the extreme value analysis (for maxima)
#can be downloaded from: 
source("http://www.datall-analyse.nl/R/eva_max.R")

#data from Castillo et al., Table 1.1, p. 9-10
#yearly maximum wind speed (in miles/hour)
evobs <- scan("http://www.datall-analyse.nl/blog_data/extremes_Table1-1.txt")

#explore data visually
options(repr.plot.width=7, repr.plot.height=7)
hist(evobs)

#Fréchet
frechetmod <- Lifedata.MLE(Surv(evobs) ~ 1, dist="frechet")
frechetmod
```

At some point, the author uses the output or the function `Lifedata.MLE()` to calculate the following return level:

> #note: for the wind data, a return period of 20 means that once every
> #20 years the wind speed is (on average) expected to be larger than
> #muG+qlev(1-1/20)*sigmaG=49.4 mph (in case of a Gumbel distribution),
> #or exp(muF+qlev(1-1/20)*sigmaF)=51.4 mph (in case of a Fréchet distribution)
> #(this expected wind speed is also called the return level)

which I suppose requires the xi shape parameter to calculate the 51.4 mph, using the quantile formula:

$$X_T=\mu +\frac{\sigma\left( 1 - \left( -\log\left(1-1/T \right)\right)^\xi\right)}{\xi}$$

where $T$ is the return period ($1/(1-F)$, where $F$ is the distribution function).

REFERENCE: [Overeem et al. (2010), *Water Resources Research*, **46**, "Extreme value modeling of areal rainfall from weather radar"](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1029/2009WR008517)

However, this parameter is not included in the output of `frechetmod`:

```
Call:
model.frame(formula = Surv(evobs) ~ 1)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    logsigma 
  3.3579367   0.1957559 

Loglikelihod:
-173.4035 (df=2)
```

How can I get this shape parameter estimate?

---

The $51.4$ value in the quoted paragraph is obtained in the post as:

```
frechetmod <- Lifedata.MLE(Surv(evobs) ~ 1, dist="frechet")
frechetmod

muF <- coef(frechetmod)[1]
sigmaF <- coef(frechetmod)[2]

exp(muF+qlev(1-1/20)*sigmaF)
```

using the `Package ‘SPREDA’` and the `qlev()` call, which gives the quantile of the Standard Largest Extreme Value Distribution, but I don't know how to reconcile with the closed equation above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're estimating the location (`(Intercept)`) & scale (`logsigma`) parameters of a log-Fréchet distribution (corresponding to a Fréchet distribution with a fixed lower bound of nought–a natural enough lower bound for wind speeds, & for many other kinds of observations). So if the density function for a Fréchet random variable $Y$, parametrized with scale $\beta$ & shape $\alpha$, is

$$f_Y(y) = \alpha\cdot\left(\frac{y}{\beta}\right)^{-(\alpha+1)} \cdot \exp\left[-\left(\frac{y}{\beta}\right)^{-\alpha}\right]$$

& given $Z = \log(Y)$

$$\begin{align}
f_Z(z) &= \alpha\cdot\left(\frac{\exp z}{\beta}\right)^{-(\alpha+1)} \cdot \exp\left[-\left(\frac{\exp z}{\beta}\right)^{-\alpha}\right] \cdot \left| \frac{\operatorname{d}\exp z}{\operatorname{d}z} \right| \\
&= \alpha\cdot \exp \{-\alpha (z-\log\beta) - \exp[-\alpha (z-\log\beta)]\}
\end{align}
$$

the location parameter of the log-Fréchet distribution will therefore be $\log\beta$ & the scale parameter $\frac{1}{\alpha}$. (In a regression model the former would be a function, perhaps a linear function, of the predictors—here of course you've fitted an intercept-only model.) And of course maximum-likelihood estimates are equivariant to parameter transformations.

Check the help pages and/or source code for the `Lifedata.MLE` function to confirm. (Note that plugging $y=51.4$, $\beta=\exp(3.3579)$ & $\alpha=\frac{1}{0.19576}$ into the Fréchet distribution function

$$
F_Y(y) = \exp\left[-\left(\frac{y}{\beta}\right)^{-\alpha}\right]
$$

gives $0.95$, which is reassuring.)

---

The above parametrization of the Fréchet can be extended to include a location parameter $\tau$, with the distribution function

$$ F_Y(y) = \exp\left[-\left(\frac{y - \tau}{\beta}\right)^{-\alpha}\right]
$$
It's a common one, with $\tau$ conveniently interpretable as the lower bound on $Y$. The parametrization you're using corresponds to the distribution function
$$ F_Y(y) = \exp\left[-\left(\frac{y - (\mu + \sigma/\xi)}{-\sigma/\xi}\right)^{1/\xi}\right]
$$
& I suppose is more suited to describing Fréchet distributions within the broader Fisher–Tippett family.

From these it's easy to see the relations:

$$
\begin{align}
\alpha &= \frac{-1}{\xi}\\
\beta &= \frac{-\sigma}{\xi}\\
\tau &= \mu + \frac{\sigma}{\xi}
\end{align}
$$

A numerical check with R confirms 51.4 mph as the return level:

```
alpha <- 1/0.1957559
beta <- exp(3.3579367)
tau <- 0

zeta <- -1/alpha
sigma <- -beta*zeta
mu <- tau - sigma/zeta

T <- 20
F <- (T-1)/T

y <- mu+sigma*(1-(-log(F))^zeta)/zeta
```

Comment: How can you get the shape parameter?

Comment: `logsigma` is an estimate of the reciprocal of the shape parameter $\xi$ of a Fréchet distribution if I'm right. At any rate there's surely not a missing parameter estimate in the output.

Comment: The `Intercept` is the **location**; the `logsigma`  is the **scale**; and $1/`logsigma`$ is the **shape** parameter? I thought there were three distinct parameters in the Frechet. I'm not following.

Comment: Is there an easy way to "confirm" that this is so by calculating the 51.4 value in the quote in the question?

Comment: `(Intercept)` is the maximum-likelihood estimate of the location parameter ($\sigma$ in the parameterization I've used) for the log-Fréchet distribution & therefore of the logarithm of the scale parameter for the Fréchet distribution. `logsigma` is the MLE of the scale parameter for the log-Fréchet distribution & therefore of the reciprocal of the shape parameter for the Fréchet distribution ($\xi$). There's no location parameter for this Fréchet distribution because the lower bound is fixed at nought (a natural enough lower bound for wind speeds, & for many other kinds of observations).

Comment: @Mathtourist: Good idea - I've included that quick check in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a million! This is perfect! And very helpful!

Comment: @Mathtourist You're welcome

Comment: Applying the quantile formula in my post, I get `muFrech = 0;
sigFrech = exp(muF);
xiFrech = 1/sigmaF;
Time = 20;

muFrech + sigFrech * (1 - (-log(1 - 1/Time))^(xiFrech) / (xiFrech))` which is 28, not the desired 51.

Comment: I got the quantile eq. from [here](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1029/2009WR008517).

Comment: @Mathtourist: I didn't notice, but your formula's for a Fisher-Tippett, a.k.a generalized extreme value distribution, so my $\xi$ isn't your $\xi$. I've changed my notation.

Comment: Do you have the close equation for the quantiles to get the $51.4$ in the question? I know how the blogger computes it by using the Standard Largest Extreme Value Distribution, but I'd like to validate the equation I typeset by avoiding recurring to the SLEVD.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect this last loose end.

Comment: The quantile function is simply the inverse of the distribution function: $F^{-1}_Y (\cdot)$. I've appended a note on different parametrizations

Comment: The inverse function is $\frac{\mu\xi + \sigma - \sigma(-\log(y))^\xi}{\xi}.$ with $\xi=-1/\alpha=-1/0.19576,$ $\sigma =-\xi/\beta=5.108/\exp(3.3579).$ Assuming $\mu=0,$ when $20$ is plugged into it, the result is a complex number... The horror!

Comment: @Mathtourist: Check your working. You already have the quantile function in your question, $\sigma=-\zeta\beta$, & $\tau=0$ but $\mu=\tau-\frac{\sigma}{\zeta}$ ($\tau$ is the lower bound on $Y$, not $\mu$).

Comment: I was inverting your last equation for the cdf disregarding the OP.

Comment: @Mathtourist: I inverted your equation to get mine. Check with `exp(-((51.4-(mu+sigma/zeta))/(-sigma/zeta))^(1/zeta))`